# Animated div with scrollTop lose animation in scrolled page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, how the code was supposed to run: if you just load the example, and click on "menu" on the bottom left, a new div cover the entire page, with another menu, sliding from the top. If you click the button again, same animation in reverse. Works fine!

But if you scroll the main page to the bottom, and then click on the menu again, it works, but when you click the menu button again, there is no animation. The menu div simply disappears. How can I fix that?

```js
menu();

function menu(nm_pagina) {
  var scroll;
  $("#menu01").click(function() {
    if ($(".menu_aberto").css("display") == 'none') {
      $(".menu_aberto").slideDown(300);
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      $(".miolo_relacionamentos").hide();
    } else {
      $(".menu_aberto").slideUp(300);
      $('.' + nm_pagina).height('auto');
      $(".miolo_relacionamentos").fadeIn(100);
      $("html").scrollTop(scroll);
    };
  });
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ft_menu_botoes {
  max-width: 800px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #162F67;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#ft_menu_botoes #menu01 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

#ft_menu_botoes #menu01 .ico_menu {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#ft_menu_botoes #menu01:active {
  background-color: #2855bb;
}

.menu_aberto {
  z-index: 9;
  max-width: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  background: #162F67;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#2855bb, #162F67);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#2855bb, #162F67);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#2855bb, #162F67);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#2855bb, #162F67);
  /* Standard syntax */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
}

.menu_aberto #fecha_menu {
  float: left;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 17px;
  color: white;
  width: 22%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lista_rel {
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #162F67;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.lista_rel:first {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.lista_rel .nome_empresa {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #162F67;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.lista_rel .nome_mae {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e3e5e7;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  color: #525860;
}

.lista_rel .posicao_empresa {
  width: 40px;
  height: 44px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.lista_rel .textos {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}

.lista_rel .textos .cnpj {
  color: #162F67;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.lista_rel .textos .cnpj span {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.lista_rel .textos .num_documentos {
  color: #525860;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 20px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.lista_rel .box_numero {
  width: 60px;
  height: 44px;
  background-color: #1f4291;
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

.lista_rel .box_numero p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.header_mob_01 {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #162F67;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.rlc {
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.miolo_relacionamentos {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=fake_code.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/relacionamentos.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/fake_code.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="vertical"></div>
  <div class="rlc">
    <div class="header_mob_01"></div>
    <div class="menu_aberto"></div>
    <div class="miolo_relacionamentos">
      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

      <div class="lista_rel">
        <h3 class="nome_empresa"> Lorem ipsum dolor </h3>
        <p class="nome_mae"> Duis ut nisi </p>
        <div class="posicao_empresa"></div>
        <div class="textos">
          <p class="cnpj"> Nullam vitae: <span> 123-456-789 </span> </p>
          <p class="num_documentos"> Integer massa </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box_numero">
          <p>999</p>
        </div>
        <p class="rl_tudo zerado"></p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="ft_menu_botoes">
      <div id="menu01"> <span class="icon-menu ico_menu"></span> <br> Menu </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

PS: sorry for the clumsy job in the html/css. Just copied the original and started deleting things which do not matter here.

Comment: Change `.menu_aberto` from `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`

Comment: damn! It worked!! Thanks :D